# Is it acceptable if a superclass contains no code?

Tags: oop, software-design

I'm pretty new to programming, and computing in general. Often I find myself needing to group many classes under a common name. For example, I might need to write a bunch of methods `eat(Orange orange)`, `eat(Apple apple)`, `eat(Kumquat kumquat)`, corresponding to, well, you know, eating oranges, apples, and kumquats. But often, it is far easier to simply write one method `eat(Fruit fruit)`. So I make a class `Fruit` that `Orange`, `Apple`, and `Kumquat` all extend, and `eat(Fruit fruit)` distinguishes among these types in its method body with an instanceof construction. But `Fruit` doesn't actually contain any methods or fields of its own; it is merely a common name that the fruits all go by.

Is this an acceptable software design pattern? It's a strong arm approach to a simple problem, which doesn't feel groovy.

If not, what is the usual alternative?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Why do you need subclasses? If those fruits all share the same attributes and methods and don't add anything special - there is no need for subclasses at all.

Comment: Having an eat(Fruit) method with a bunch of instance of inside doesn't sound like good design to me. Overload the method or use polimorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What use is a type with no members? It will be hard to treat it polymorphically, unless you cast it to one of the subtypes (which you shouldn't).

```
public void Eat(Fruit fruit)
{
    //What do I do with the fruit now?
    //I can't call any method on it, or retrieve any data from it
}
```

---

> `eat(Fruit fruit)` distinguishes among these types in its method body with an instanceof construction

This is a code smell. It breaks the [Open-Closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and the [principle of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and is a bad practice.

Imagine I decide to derive from `Fruit` and add a class named `Mango`. If I then call your `Eat` method, it won't work - because it only works for *certain* kinds of fruits, not for any fruit.

Comment: Which class is violating the Open-Closed principle, exactly? `Fruit` or one of its subclasses? Or the code containing the `eat` method?

Comment: @Mickeysofine The `eat` method violates the Open Closed principle. If you decide to add another class named `Mango` which also derives from `Fruit`, you'll have to change the `eat` method to account for this new kind of fruit. The Open-Closed principle states that you shouldn't have to change the code in `eat` for *any* reason other than to change how fruits are eaten. I've updated my answer, it should be more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is acceptable, and it is even a good practice.

Your superclass might have no code as of now, but having the superclass reduce refactoring effort when you do need a common behaviour.

Also, if you ever use generics, you can specify that your object should extend Fruit, which limit the number of object on which you can call the method.

In java :
void <TFruit extends Fruit> eat(TFruit fruit);

instead of :
void <TFruit> eat(TFruit fruit);

The 2nd method could be called on any object (a StringBuilder for example), and you clearly can't eat a string builder.

Edit:
However, your object design is bizarre. A fruit shouldn't eat. A person, or an animal eats a fruit. The method eat probably shouldn't belong to Fruit. Also, as previously said, having one method with multiple ifs to pinpoint behaviour is a bad practice.

Comment: In this case you should perhaps use an interface (as marker interface, which is itself arguable). If it becomes necessary to add code, you may add an abstract base implementation afterwards.